# php jquery onclick not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick

I am trying to achieve an on-click event on multiple buttons with the help of jQuery. 
These buttons are coming from php file.

php code:

```
<?php 


    require_once './common/db_connect.php';
        $db_connection = db_connect();
        $select_query = "SELECT term_id, term, status, active FROM term WHERE active = 1";
        $statement = $db_connection -> query($select_query);
        $result = $statement -> fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        foreach($result as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row->term.'</td>';
                echo '<td><button value="'.$row->status.'">'.$row->status.'</button></td>';
                echo '<td>'.(($row->active == 1) ? 'Yes' : 'No').'</td>';
                echo '<td><button class = "delete" data-id='.$row->term_id.'>Delete</button></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
```

In the above code, I have a button with class="delete" and on this, I like to have an on-click event but it is not working.

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('tbody').html(data);
                }
            })

            $('.delete').on('click', function() {
                alert("this is working");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to move `$('.delete').on('click', ...` inside `success` handler.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now! :)
Thank you for your time

Comment: your problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331127/4126424